# Calculate percentage of total when this percentage is also part of the total

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have some easy variables and 1 stinker involved in calculating the Final Price I can charge for an item.
All costs (NOT the Base) are added to get the Total Price.
In the example below, Var 3 is calculated from the resulting total but is also INCLUDED in the total.

Example:

```
Base Value:   $10.00 (2 values are calculated from this number)
+ Var 1: 50% of Base:  $ 5.00
+ Var 2: 10% of Base:  $ 1.00
+ Fixed Cost:          $ 4.00 (always fixed regardless of Base or total)
=   Subtotal ------    $10.00 
+ Var 3. 15% of Total  $ ????
=   TOTAL    ------    $ ??????  ($10 + whatever Var 3 is)
```

There are multiple Base Values so I need a formula that can work with different values. How can I calculate this without guessing and recalculating until I find the right value.

Thanks!

Comment: Just use algebra  $T = Subtotal + .15 T$  So $.85 T = Subtotal$ and $T = Subtotal/.85$ and Var 3 = $.15*Subtotal/.85= 3*Subtotal/17$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use algebra

Total = Subtotal + .15 Total

So

.85 Total = Subtotal

Total = Subtotal/.85

Var 3 = .15 Subtotal/.85 = 3 Subtotal/17

Or more thoroughly....

Let $B = $ base cost.

Var 1 = $.5*B$

Var 2 = $.1*B$

Fixed Cost = $4$

SubTotal = Var 1 + Var 2 + Fixed Cost = $.5B + .1B + 4.00 = .6B + 4.00$.

Var 3 = $.15*$ Total=$.15 X$.

$X$ = Total = Subtotal + Var 3 = $.6B + 4.00 + .15X$

So $X = .6B + 4 + .15X$

$X - .15X = .6B +4 + .15X - .15X$

$.85 X = .6B + 4$

$.85 X/.85 = (.6B + 4)/.85$

$X = \frac {.6}{.85}B + \frac 4{.85} = \frac {60}{85}B + \frac {400}{85}=\frac {12}{17}B + 4\frac {12}{17}$.

Var 3 = $.15X = .15(\frac {60}{85}B + \frac {400}{85}) = \frac 9{85}B + \frac {12}{17}=\frac 3{17}(.6B + 4) = \frac 3{17}Subtotal$

Comment: Works for me.  Going to take some cypherin'.  Appreciate your thorough explanation which will certainly help me to make sense of it!